# how can we inject a PHP variable into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a problem with the "windows.location" command in JavaScript. I would like to add the php variable in the link windows.location. How can i do?
For example: I would like to transfer user to English page or Vietnamese Page by variable $lang

Here is my code

echo 'window.location="/B2C/$lang/confirm_fone.html"';

and the result in address bar is:

```
http://10.160.64.4:1234/B2C/$lang/confirm_fone.html
```

the $lang in address bar cannot be decode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables in single-quoted strings don't get interpolated in PHP.

Use this instead:

```
echo 'window.location="/B2C/' . $lang . '/confirm_fone.html"';
```

Or use doublequotes:

```
echo "window.location='/B2C/$lang/confirm_fone.html'";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the whole string is in single quotes.

You'll want to use double quotes for interpolation.

Otherwise, you can try:

```
echo 'window.location="/B2C/'.$lang.'/confirm_fone.html"';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put php variables within the string you should use Double Quotes .

```
echo "window.location='/B2C/$lang/confirm_fone.html'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the value, as follows :

```
echo 'window.location="/B2C/'.$lang.'/confirm_fone.html"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not resolved by PHP in Strings when you use the `'` as delimiter. Use `"` instead (and `'` for the javascript command) or concatenate the String using `.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in php-context:

```
echo "window.location=\"/B2C/"{$lang}"/confirm_fone.html\";';
```

If you are in HTML-Context (or better "outer-php-context"):

```
window.location="/B2C/<?php echo $lang ?>/confirm_fone.html";
```